# Prometheus query for dependency mapping, ideally that shows "source" or similar?

Tags: dependencies, prometheus, grafana

I am trying to determine if a Prometheus data source can be used to visualize dependencies.

I've looked through the [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/) but I haven't been able to determine which query would be useful for mapping out the dependencies.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of a query that has the Origin of a request, or something similar that could suit my use case?

For more context, I'm determining whether I can use the Grafana Dependency Graph plugin, but so far, I haven't been able to successful map any of the Prometheus queries I've tried to build out a graph.

Comment: See [this github issue](https://github.com/NovatecConsulting/novatec-service-dependency-graph-panel/issues/94). Apparently, all you have to do is to prepare the data in table format.